# I'm struggling with prepared statement, in which

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement, mariadb, concatenation

...table name is the parameter. I found the solution here: [unable to store return value from execute statement in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296386/unable-to-store-return-value-from-execute-statement-in-mysql)
but it's not working for me. Here's my test:

```
SET @v_sourceTableSize = 0;
SET @parameter_sourceTable = category;
SET @v_query = CONCAT("SELECT COUNT(*) INTO ",@v_sourceTableSize," FROM ",@parameter_sourceTable);
```

category is a table in my db. When I run this, nothing happens. No error, nothing. Is there a way to make it work? I've been looking for a solution since the morning!

**EDIT**
I placed "category" between quotes and now it is working, however my original procedure does not. Please have a look:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insert_categories;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_categories(
    IN parameter_sourceTableIdColumnName INTEGER,
    IN parameter_sourceTable VARCHAR(25),
    IN parameter_sourceColumn VARCHAR(25),
    IN parameter_destinationParentCategoryID INTEGER)

    MODIFIES SQL DATA

    BEGIN
        DECLARE v_parameterSourceTable VARCHAR(25) DEFAULT "";
        DECLARE v_sourceTableSize INTEGER;
        DECLARE v_counter INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE v_query VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT "";
        DECLARE v_recordName VARCHAR(25) DEFAULT "";
        SET v_parameterSourceTable = parameter_sourceTable;
        SET v_query = CONCAT("SELECT COUNT(*) INTO ",v_sourceTableSize," FROM ",v_parameterSourceTable);
        PREPARE stmt FROM v_query;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        SELECT v_sourceTableSize;
        #SET v_sourceTableSize := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM parameter_sourceTable);
        SET v_sourceTableSize = v_sourceTableSize + 1;
        WHILE v_counter < v_sourceTableSize DO
            SET v_counter = v_counter + 1;
            SET v_recordName = (SELECT parameter_sourceColumn 
                                FROM v_parameterSourceTable 
                                WHERE parameter_sourceTableIdColumnName = v_counter);
            CALL insertCategory(v_recordName, parameter_destinationParentCategoryID);
        END WHILE;
    END $$    
DELIMITER ;
```

I'm getting this error:

1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'v_query;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        SELECT v_sourceTableSize;
                SET v_sourceTa' at line 17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A prepared statement can access user-defined variables, but not local
>   variables or procedure's parameters.

```
    SET @v_query = CONCAT("SELECT COUNT(*) INTO ",v_sourceTableSize," FROM ",v_parameterSourceTable);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @v_query;
    EXECUTE stmt;
```

[Docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/prepare-statement/)

Comment: 7 years later...: Thanks bud